# Removing duplicate words in url and filtering out words not in a list

Tags: c#, regex

I have a links that the sub category got repeated a bunch of times. Also only want to keep the repeating if they are in a certain list. But also keep the last part of the link
About
Video
Example1
Example2

www.example.com/About/About/Videos/Videos/Videos/Featured/5-great-videos

should be

www.example.com/about/videos/5-great-videos

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one, using LINQ

```
string str = "www.example.com/About/About/Videos/Videos/Videos/Featured/5-great-videos";
var result = str.Split('/').GroupBy(x=>x).Select(x=>x.Key).Aggregate((a,b)=>a+"/"+b);
```

Comment: And if you only want to keep the ones in a certain list, add a `Where` before the `Aggregate`.

Answer (score -1):

In case you prefer not using linq:

```
string url = "www.example.com/About/About/Videos/Videos/Videos/Featured/5-great-videos";
List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
foreach (string urlToken in url.Split('/'))
    if (!urlList.Contains(urlToken)) urlList.Add(urlToken);
url = String.Join("/", urlList.ToArray());
```